# Certbot en dominio ".uy" apuntando a "noip"

Tags: apache, ssl, https, certificado-ssl

primero daré un poco de contexto.

Actualmente tengo un servidor con Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS, donde tengo instalado apache como servidor web, para acceder a este tengo un servicio **noip** supongamos `example.ddns.net`, y tengo un dominio `www.example.uy` apuntando a este noip.

Hasta ahora todo correcto, esto funciona muy bien, ahora intento ponerle un certificado ssl a esto usando *certbot*, siguiendo su guía en línea (muy bien explicado en mi opinión cabe aclarar jeje) y luego de concluir con todos los pasos obtengo un:

```
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.uy/fullchain.pem
```

Luego de ver esto se podrán imaginar la alegría que me dio jaja, reinicie los servicios de apache y fui a probar mi nuevo ssl... para darme cuenta que PUF, se quedaba cargando un rato y luego me mandaba un `No se puede acceder a este sitio web` (aclaro que el dominio ahora se cambio por un `https://www.example.uy/` por lo que algo si hizo) y yo pensando: que rompí jaja.

Ingrese al servidor por el noip directamente y funcionaba bien. luego de buscar un poco vi que alguien decía que en realidad el `www.example.uy` no era mas que una redirección y tenia que poner el ssl directamente en `example.ddns.net`, cosa que hice sin problemas y me tiro otro `Congratulations!` y luego de intentarlo nuevamente pues... otra vez se quedaba cargando y PUF `No se puede acceder a este sitio web` jaja

Por suerte para mi tenia otro dominio `www.example2.uy` apuntando al **noip** y este si andaba jaja y yo estaba como WTF...

En resumen lo que quedo claro es que no entiendo nada de como funciona SSL y venia aca por un poco de guía en este tema, para saber si hay algo que estoy haciendo mal, o directamente **noip** no sirve para esto.

Desde ya muchas gracias por la paciencia de leer todo esto jaja.

PD: También vi una forma que era usando DNS y no se que cosa pero ahí ya entendí menos que menos y no quise ni entrarle, si me dicen que es la única forma pues le entrare jaja.

PD2: Se me olvido mencionarlo pero si tengo configurado el ufw para que permita acceso al https e incluso luego intente deshabilitarlo del todo pero sin suerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues contra todo pronostico lo e podido resolver, mas rápido de lo que esperaba jaja.

Dejo aca la solución por si alguien se encuentra en esta situación, aunque siento decepcionarles mi error fue mas de descuido que otra cosa.

`En resumen, me falto abrir el puerto 443 en el router y apuntarlo a mi servidor, las conexiones https se conectan atreves del 443 y no el 80 jajaja.`

En fin como dije una solución un poco tonta pero, desde mi lado estoy agradecido que fuera una tontería y no algo mas grave como tocar archivos de configuración jajaja.

Desde ya muchas gracias por quien se tomo la paciencia de leer esto y si a alguien le sirvió o le entretuvo pues bien ahí jajaja.